# Upper bound on difference of expected values between two close distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, approximation-theory

Let $p,q$ be two distributions over the same finite set $X$ and the total variation distance $TV(p,q)=\epsilon$. If for some function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, $0\leq \sum_{x\in X} f(x) p(x)\leq 1$ and $0\leq \sum_{x\in X} f(x)q(x)\leq 1$ hold. What is the best upper bound of $$\Big|\sum_x f(x)(p(x)-q(x))\Big|$$ as a function of $\epsilon$? I can only get a trivial upper bound $2$ by triangle inequality, but the constraint that the total variance distance is $\epsilon$ is not used. Is it possible to get a better bound?

Answer (score 1):

You can bound it by
$$
\left| \sum_x f(x)(p(x) - q(x)) \right| \leq \max_x |f(x)| \cdot \sum_x |p(x) - q(x)| = \epsilon \cdot \max_x |f(x)|
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think it works fine when $f$ is bounded. When $\max_x |f(x)|>2/\epsilon$, the trivial bound looks better. Is it possible to use the assumptions to argue $|f(x)|$ must be small?

Comment: $X$ is a finite set, so $f$ has to be be bounded.  The assumptions don't imply that $f$ has to be small everywhere, the best they can say is that if $f(x)$ is big, then $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ must be small.  The estimate I used in my answer is really just a special case of Hölder's inequality, so you can do any other similar estimate by changing the exponents you use.  For example, you could also say $| \sum f(x)(p(x) - q(x)) | \leq \max |p(x)-q(x)| \cdot \sum |f(x)| \leq \epsilon \sum |f(x)|$